# Is there any option to change the behavior of HAP when a pre block has an unencoded <?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, pre

When the following `<pre>` is loaded:

```
<pre><code>info.bmiHeader.biLowBit = 0; /* low bit for the pixel data (0 <= biLowBit <= biHighBit <= biBitCount-1) */
info.bmiHeader.biHighBit = 9; /* 10-1 = 9. high bit for pixel data. */
info.bmiHeader.biFlags = LGRY_BITRANGE_VALID; /* only biLowBit and biHighBit are valid */
/* Since this case does not use the LUT, it is enough to set only the fields of LGRYVIDEOINFO up to and including bmiHeader. The useful size of the
LGRYVIDEOINFO structure is offsetof(LGRYVIDEOINFO, bmiColors). */</code></pre>
```

Using HtmlDocument.Load:

```
public static HtmlDocument LoadAsHtmlDocumentFromFile(string htmlFile)
{
    var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.Load(htmlFile, Encoding.UTF8);
    Assert.IsNotNull(htmlDocument);
    return htmlDocument;
}
```

I end up with HTML (DocumentNode.OuterHtml) that looks something like this:

```
<pre><code>info.bmiHeader.biLowBit = 0; /* low bit for the pixel data (0 <= bilowbit=""><= bihighbit=""><= bibitcount-1)="" */="" info.bmiheader.bihighbit="9;" 10-1="9." high="" bit="" for="" pixel="" data.="" */="" info.bmiheader.biflags="LGRY_BITRANGE_VALID;" only="" bilowbit="" and="" bihighbit="" are="" valid="" */="" since="" this="" case="" does="" not="" use="" the="" lut,="" it="" is="" enough="" to="" set="" only="" the="" fields="" of="" lgryvideoinfo="" up="" to="" and="" including="" bmiheader.="" the="" useful="" size="" of="" the="" lgryvideoinfo="" structure="" is="" offsetof(lgryvideoinfo,="" bmicolors).="" */=""> </code></pre>
```

To me, it looks like HAP is creating a node for `=` and then making everything that follows an attribute.

If I encode the `<` as `&lt;`, then it loads the node correctly.  The problem is I have about 20K files to process and HAP does not thrown an exception, nor are there items in the `ParserErrors` collection.

Is there any option to change the behavior of HAP when a pre block has an unencoded `<`?